# Call method in extended template after all blocks have been parsed

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I have two methods, `set_page_title` and `get_page_title`. `set_page_title` is called by `child.html`, which extends `base.html` which then calls `get_page_title`.

`set_page_title` adds an attribute to the global `g` object, which `get_page_title` then reads from.

I expected `get_page_title` to be called last, because it's in a decorating view, but it is actually called first. Is there anyway I can delay the execution of `get_page_title` until after all child templates have been fully parsed?

Comment: Are you trying to set the parent page's `title` tag value from the child? There might be a better way of doing that.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are trying to replicate functionality that is already available to you in Jinja's `block`s:

```
{# base.html #}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>{% block title %}Default Title{% endblock %} - Site Name</title>
</head>
<body>
<main>
<h1>{{ self.title() }}</h1>
</main>
</body>
</html>
```

Then, in the child template you only need to override the block:

```
{# child.html #}
{% block title %}Child Title{% endblock %}
```